# folder copy in Finder labels it as incomplete, though copying is completed

Tags: finder, macos

I am getting this error much too often. I am copying a big number of files from a slow device (external hard drive) to my Mac. When the copy is completed, the last top folder is still marked as "incomplete".

[image]

I only managed to clear the mark by creating an empty folder with a different name (say "Folder2"), moving the contents of the folder (say "Folder") there, erasing the (now empty) folder "Folder" and renaming "Folder2". That all looks weird to me. Any suggestions?

**Update:** External drive is formatted in FAT32.

Comment: Is the external HD formatted with HFS (Mac OS X) or FAT32 (Windows)?

Comment: Looks like the copy is complete, but the icon just hasn't updated properly. Did you try ejecting the drive and then reconnecting? That should force the icon to change.

Comment: @amanthethy Ejecting external drive does not make any difference, the drive is ejecting successfully, and the copying is not continuing after reconnection.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking 'Get Info' and see if it works for you. I know its stupid but it should work.

Comment: Great tip! Just needed that today!